# Creating UI download button in Google Earth Engine APP

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, download, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to create a button that download images without clicking the RUN button on the task tab. I want to do this for a GEE App, where is no possible for the user to go to the task tab and click Run.

Is this possible?

See my button so far:

```
function downloadImg() {
  // Get start and end dates from button selections 
  var startDate = startYear.getValue() + "-" + month[startMonth.getValue()][0]; 
  var endDate = endYear.getValue() + "-" + month[endMonth.getValue()][0];
  // Filter the collection by dates selected.
  var filterCollection = wetlands.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                        .filterBounds(getSelectedFeatures());
  // Create mosaic
  var mosaicImage = filterCollection.max().clip(getSelectedFeatures());
  
  // Export the image to Drive.
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mosaicImage.toByte(),
  description: 'Wetland_Mosaic',
  scale: 1.8,
  region: getSelectedFeatures(),
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
  });
}

// Download button
var downloadButton = ui.Button({
  label: 'Download', style: {padding:'0px 0px 0px 10px'}
})
downloadButton.onClick(downloadImg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `Export.image.toDrive`, `image.getThumbURL` does not need the additional step of clicking "Run". Documentation for that is at the end of the page [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization).

So use I suggest you use `mosaicImage.toByte().getThumbURL()`, and print the URL to the right panel, which will let the users to click and see the image. Keep in mind that unlike the `Export.image.toDrive`, getThumbURL works for small images only.

Since you did not provide a full example, [here is one](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c734c7368599ba5ede610c931a72ba81). In lines 142 - 170, there is an export button along with the `exportImage` function you are interested in. For the App user, the app would look something like [this](https://kkraoj.users.earthengine.app/view/damagemap).

Comment: I wanted to allow the user to download a .tiff image, but I think that is not possible using the App interface. Thank you for sharing that great example, I will probably use your method.